# Display card and table inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create webpage from twitter bootstrap.I used card and table properties there.Problem im getting here is my table is displaying below card.I tried adding `float-right float-left` classes but that is not working.i want card to float left and table on right side on large screens and both responsive on small screen.Any idea how can i do it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <!--Card-->
     <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
         <!--Image-->
         <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&amp;bg=55595c&amp;fg=eceeef&amp;text=Thumbnail" alt="Item_name" style="width: 100%; display: block;" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22348%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20348%20225%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_161ad3c12bc%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23eceeef%3Bfont-weight%3Abold%3Bfont-family%3AArial%2C%20Helvetica%2C%20Open%20Sans%2C%20sans-serif%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A17pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_161ad3c12bc%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22348%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20fill%3D%22%2355595c%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22116.5%22%20y%3D%22120.3%22%3EThumbnail%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" data-holder-rendered="true">
         <!--Below Image-->
         <div class="card-body">
          <!--Item-Name-->
           <p class="card-text item-header"><i class="fa fa-hashtag"></i>1  Item 1</p>
           <!--Affiliate Section-->
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
           <div class="btn-group mb-2 affilaite-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary amazon" a href="" style="text-decoration: none;"><i class="fa fa-amazon" style="color: #0E0B16;"></i> Amazon</a></button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary amazedon-2" a href="" style="text-decoration: none;"> 400</button>
           </div>  
         </div>
          <div class="btn-group affilaite-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary ebay" a href="" style="text-decoration: none;"><img class="ebayed" src="flipkart.svg" alt="" style="color:#0E0B16;height: 18px;"> ebay</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary flab" a href="" style="text-decoration: none;">500</button>
           </div>
           </div>
       </div>        <!--Specification Table-->
      <table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
       <tbody>
            <tr>
            <th>OS</th>
            <td>Android Marshmallow 6.0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>STORAGE</th>
            <td>Internal: 32 / 64 GB<br>
              Expandable: Yes (128 GB)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>RAM</th>
            <td>2/3/4 GB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Battery & SIM</th>
            <td>Dual Sim (1 nano & 1 micro) 4GLTE<br>
                4100mAh Non-Removable</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Camera</th>
            <td><span class="td-bold" style="font-weight: 700;">Rear:</span> 13 MP (CMOS Camera,f2.0 Aperature)<br><span class="td-bold" style="font-weight: 700;">Front:</span> 5 MP (1080p Full HD Video Recording)
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Processor</th>
            <td>Qualcomm  Snapdragon 625 Octa-Core<br>
            Adreno 506</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Dispaly</th>
            <td>1920 x 1080 5.5 inch (401ppi) IPS LCD</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Start by fixing your invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Edited your html code .you have put both `card` and `table`  `col-md-4`.
I have changed it

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <!--Card-->
     <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
         <!--Image-->
         <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&amp;bg=55595c&amp;fg=eceeef&amp;text=Thumbnail" alt="Item_name" style="width: 100%; display: block;" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22348%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20348%20225%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_161ad3c12bc%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23eceeef%3Bfont-weight%3Abold%3Bfont-family%3AArial%2C%20Helvetica%2C%20Open%20Sans%2C%20sans-serif%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A17pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_161ad3c12bc%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22348%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20fill%3D%22%2355595c%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22116.5%22%20y%3D%22120.3%22%3EThumbnail%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" data-holder-rendered="true">
         <!--Below Image-->
         <div class="card-body">
          <!--Item-Name-->
           <p class="card-text item-header"><i class="fa fa-hashtag"></i>1  Item 1</p>
           <!--Affiliate Section-->
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
           <div class="btn-group mb-2 affilaite-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary amazon" a href="" style="text-decoration: none;"><i class="fa fa-amazon" style="color: #0E0B16;"></i> Amazon</a></button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary amazedon-2" a href="" style="text-decoration: none;"> 400</button>
           </div>  
         </div>
          <div class="btn-group affilaite-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary ebay" a href="" style="text-decoration: none;"><img class="ebayed" src="flipkart.svg" alt="" style="color:#0E0B16;height: 18px;"> ebay</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary flab" a href="" style="text-decoration: none;">500</button>
           </div>
           </div>
       </div>        <!--Specification Table-->
    </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
       <tbody>
            <tr>
            <th>OS</th>
            <td>Android Marshmallow 6.0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>STORAGE</th>
            <td>Internal: 32 / 64 GB<br>
              Expandable: Yes (128 GB)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>RAM</th>
            <td>2/3/4 GB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Battery & SIM</th>
            <td>Dual Sim (1 nano & 1 micro) 4GLTE<br>
                4100mAh Non-Removable</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Camera</th>
            <td><span class="td-bold" style="font-weight: 700;">Rear:</span> 13 MP (CMOS Camera,f2.0 Aperature)<br><span class="td-bold" style="font-weight: 700;">Front:</span> 5 MP (1080p Full HD Video Recording)
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Processor</th>
            <td>Qualcomm  Snapdragon 625 Octa-Core<br>
            Adreno 506</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Dispaly</th>
            <td>1920 x 1080 5.5 inch (401ppi) IPS LCD</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code it's works for me, this fully responsive :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <!--Card-->
        <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
          <!--Image-->
          <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&amp;bg=55595c&amp;fg=eceeef&amp;text=Thumbnail" alt="Item_name"
            style="width: 100%; display: block;" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22348%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20348%20225%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_161ad3c12bc%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23eceeef%3Bfont-weight%3Abold%3Bfont-family%3AArial%2C%20Helvetica%2C%20Open%20Sans%2C%20sans-serif%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A17pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_161ad3c12bc%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22348%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20fill%3D%22%2355595c%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22116.5%22%20y%3D%22120.3%22%3EThumbnail%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"
            data-holder-rendered="true">
          <!--Below Image-->
          <div class="card-body">
            <!--Item-Name-->
            <p class="card-text item-header">
              <i class="fa fa-hashtag"></i>1 Item 1</p>
            <!--Affiliate Section-->
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <div class="btn-group mb-2 affilaite-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary amazon">
                  <a href="" style="text-decoration: none;">
                    <i class="fa fa-amazon" style="color: #0E0B16;"></i>
                    Amazon</a>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary amazedon-2" a href="" style="text-decoration: none;"> 400</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group affilaite-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary ebay" style="text-decoration: none;">
                <img class="ebayed" src="flipkart.svg" alt="" style="color:#0E0B16;height: 18px;"> ebay </button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary flab">
                500
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
        <!--Specification Table-->
        <table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>OS</th>
              <td>Android Marshmallow 6.0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>STORAGE</th>
              <td>Internal: 32 / 64 GB
                <br> Expandable: Yes (128 GB)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>RAM</th>
              <td>2/3/4 GB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Battery & SIM</th>
              <td>Dual Sim (1 nano & 1 micro) 4GLTE
                <br> 4100mAh Non-Removable</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Camera</th>
              <td>
                <span class="td-bold" style="font-weight: 700;">Rear:</span> 13 MP (CMOS Camera,f2.0 Aperature)
                <br>
                <span class="td-bold" style="font-weight: 700;">Front:</span> 5 MP (1080p Full HD Video Recording)
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Processor</th>
              <td>Qualcomm Snapdragon 625 Octa-Core
                <br> Adreno 506</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Dispaly</th>
              <td>1920 x 1080 5.5 inch (401ppi) IPS LCD</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```